# Cwac-Camera out file size issue on specific devices

Tags: android, camera, commonsware-cwac

I am using [CWAC - Camera library](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-camera) to integrate custom camera in my app.

It works fine as expected on all devices which i have, except on Moto E & Moto G.

When i capture Single Shot image with above devices, i don't get desired size output image.

When i go to capture SingleShot image, getLargestPictureSize (CameraUtils) method returns highest size which camera supports like 1944*2592 (h*w) and the same set in Camera parameters before capture but output file is generated with 1280*720 (h*w).

Can anyone guide me towards possible issue?

**getLargestPictureSize method**

```
public static Camera.Size getLargestPictureSize(CameraHost host,
                                                  Camera.Parameters parameters,
                                                  boolean enforceProfile) {
    Camera.Size result=null;

    for (Camera.Size size : parameters.getSupportedPictureSizes()) {

      // android.util.Log.d("CWAC-Camera",
      // String.format("%d x %d", size.width, size.height));

      if (!enforceProfile
          || (size.height <= host.getDeviceProfile()
                                 .getMaxPictureHeight() && size.height >= host.getDeviceProfile()
                                                                              .getMinPictureHeight())) {
        if (result == null) {
          result=size;
        }
        else {
          int resultArea=result.width * result.height;
          int newArea=size.width * size.height;

          if (newArea > resultArea) {
            result=size;
          }
        }
      }
    }

    if (result == null && enforceProfile) {
      result=getLargestPictureSize(host, parameters, false);
    }

    return(result);
  }
```

**Capture method**

```
public void takePicture(final PictureTransaction xact) {
    if (inPreview) {
      if (isAutoFocusing) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(
                                        "Camera cannot take a picture while auto-focusing");
      }
      else {
        previewParams=camera.getParameters();

        Camera.Parameters pictureParams=camera.getParameters();
        Camera.Size pictureSize=
            xact.host.getPictureSize(xact, pictureParams);

        pictureParams.setPictureSize(pictureSize.width,
                                     pictureSize.height);
        pictureParams.setPictureFormat(ImageFormat.JPEG);
//        pictureParams.setColorEffect(Parameters.EFFECT_MONO);
        if (xact.flashMode != null) {
          pictureParams.setFlashMode(xact.flashMode);
        }

        if (!onOrientationChange.isEnabled()) {
          setCameraPictureOrientation(pictureParams);
        }

        camera.setParameters(xact.host.adjustPictureParameters(xact,
                                                               pictureParams));
        xact.cameraView=this;

        camera.autoFocus(new AutoFocusCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onAutoFocus(boolean success, final Camera camera) {
                        postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                try {
                                    camera.takePicture(
                                            xact,
                                            null,
                                            new PictureTransactionCallback(xact));
                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                    android.util.Log.e(getClass()
                                            .getSimpleName(),
                                            "Exception taking a picture", e);
                                    // TODO get this out to library clients
                                }
                            }
                        }, xact.host.getDeviceProfile().getPictureDelay());
            }
        });


        inPreview=false;
      }
    }
    else {
      throw new IllegalStateException(
                                      "Preview mode must have started before you can take a picture");
    }
  }
```

Comment: When you try the demo app, do you get the same behavior?

Comment: Yes i do get the same behavior.

Comment: I tested on Samsung galaxy S2 with same scenario in CameraDemo app, i get following result : 
`getLargestPictureSize
2448*3264 (h*w),

Output
3264*2448 (h*w)`

Comment: If you can tell me the `Build.PRODUCT` values for one or both of those devices, I can work on getting my hands on one to try to reproduce the problem. If it is happening with the demo app, it's clearly something with the library.

Comment: Moto E device : 
Build.MANUFACTURER = motorola,
Build.PRODUCT = condor_retaildsds, Android Version = 4.4.4

Comment: OK, the E looks like it is perhaps the XT1022 model.

Comment: I have one on order -- I'll report back next week with the results of my tests.

Comment: Okay no issues, but on the fly can you suggest some of the possible issue, or point which i may have missed while debugging to solve this.

Comment: If it occurs in the demo app, by definition, it cannot be something from your code. That's why I asked about whether you could reproduce the problem in the demo app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce your problem. Most size requests are ignored. My guess is that this device, like some others, does not like my changing camera parameters on the fly. I am going to replace CWAC-Camera with a new library which will stop doing that, plus add support for Android 5.0's `android.hardware.camera2` API. Hopefully, this problem will be fixed at that point.

I have filed [an issue](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-camera/issues/274) for this on the existing library, so I know to specifically work on this scenario.

Comment: I found the same, that most size requests are being ignored in some devices like MOTO e (XT1022) and MOTO g (X1032). Thanks for your response and confirmation on this issue.